# Errors converting web site project to web application project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I have a web site that I am trying to convert to a web application project.  I am using these references:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2009/10/29/converting-a-web-site-project-to-a-web-application-project.aspx

I think I'm following the recipe, but I get hundreds of compilation errors upon build, which in my experience usually means I am doing something very basic very wrong, like in web.config.  Without posting the entire project, here's a sample of the errors.

In each web form, the asp.net page directive looks like this:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Configuration" Codebehind="Configuration.aspx.cs" %>`

And throws:  "The pre-application start initialzation method Start on type System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode" threw an exception with the following error message: Could not find a part of the path 'I:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MG401k\WAP\MG401kWap'"  and  "A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods".  It looks like it is expecting something that I am not telling it.  If I add a new web form to the project, the page directive looks like this:

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MG401kWap.WebForm1" %>`

but still throws the same error.

In each javascript file, for the "$(document).ready" function, it throws "error CS1056: Unexpected character '$'"

I added 
`<namespaces>
          <add namespace="MG401kWap" />
      </namespaces></code>`
to the web.config, but no joy.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I'm unsure what to do next.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

There are a few suggestions [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1511968.aspx?jQuery%20with%20ASP%20NET) that you might be able to try, specifically making sure that the jquery references are before any other script references in your pages.

Not sure about the page directive errors so far, though :/

Comment: No, they're all defined like so:`<script src="AppError.aspx.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`  I agree with the question you referenced that the C# compiler doesn't seem to understand that's javascript right there, but now what?